# Pass NSArray to UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I presumed this would be simple but it is not working.

I am trying to pass an NSArray to my UIView that is getting imported with a NIB.I am importing it as:

```
 DraggableViewBackground *draggableBackground = [[DraggableViewBackground alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    draggableBackground.exampleCardLabels = @[@"Mercedes-Benz", @"BMW", @"Porsche",
                                              @"Opel", @"Volkswagen", @"Audi"];
    [self.ripContainer addSubview:draggableBackground];
```

On my **DraggableViewBackground** UIView

**.h**

```
 @property (retain,nonatomic)NSArray* exampleCardLabels;
```

**.m**

```
    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
        {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {

            [super layoutSubviews];

            NSLog(@"Dish RIP %@", exampleCardLabels);

                   }

         return self;

         }
```

I am currently getting a **null** value. I am aware this is 101 basics when passing data but I don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: You're getting a null value where exactly?

Comment: My NSLog is producing a null value which I take it to mean the NSArray hasn't passed

Comment: This makes no sense! You are logging the exampleCardLabels values  in (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame but you have  not initialised it then. How do expect it to return values

Comment: @Allreadyhome you are setting the `exampleCardLabels` after your `NSLog` (which is in `initWithFrame:` in the code above)

Comment: @albertamg your comment actual explained it best. My oversight. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `init` like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andCards:(NSArray *)cards{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self){
        self.xampleCardLabels = cards;
    }
    return self;
}
```

and call it

```
 DraggableViewBackground *draggableBackground = [[DraggableViewBackground alloc]
                                                            initWithFrame: frame 
                                                                 andCards: @[@"Mercedes-Benz", @"BMW", @"Porsche",@"Opel", @"Volkswagen", @"Audi"]];
```

Answer (score 3):

It's just timing.

At this stage the array has not been set:

```
DraggableViewBackground *draggableBackground = [[DraggableViewBackground alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
```

and yet you are logging the array in the `initWithFrame` method.  Log it later on in the lifecycle.

Also don't call `[super layoutSubviews];` in the `initWithFrame` method.